# Is there a field length that is too short to allow harmful SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection

I was reading about SQL injection and saw this, which got me thinking:

> input fields as small as possible to reduce the likelihood of a hacker being able to squeeze SQL code into the field without it being truncated (which usually leads to a T-SQL syntax error).

Source: *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Unleashed*

What is the is the shortest field size where SQL injection can cause harm?

With harm being database modification or returning results not intended by design. Including an end comment marker (`--`) in a two character field would not cause harm, it would just cause a failed query. The potential hacker, might learn the field is susceptible to injection, but they are unable to leverage it.

Comment: If the error given is verbose, that might be enough to get useful information, especially where a developer has treated table names as "secret"...

Comment: SQL Injection isn't always done on an input field - you can target orderby clauses in URLs for example where you could execute malicious sql. The limited size of a field isn't going to stop that.

Comment: @iain: Good point. Also, limiting field lengths for (I assume) received HTML form data doesn't strike me as a good way to avoid sql injection. SQL injection avoidance is basically a solved problem; just let the database connection library handle it by using prepared statements with placeholders, instead of pasting together queries using your programming language's string functions and getting it wrong because you forgot to protect against loophole number 59654.

Comment: @Pascal "*SQL injection avoidance is basically a solved problem;*" only applies to new code where appropriate considerations have been applied. There is much existing code where the problem has not been addressed. Presumably there is a character length below which addressing existing issues are less pressing then those with longer lengths.

Comment: Am I the only one which thinks that book should be publicly burned? Parameterized queries have been around for so long that the author leads me to believe that they don't have even half a clue what they are talking about. It sounds like they copy+pasted garbage from a collection of blogs and released a book. They might as well tell you that you should practice getting shot with smaller bullets so that you can build up immunity to larger bullets.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus <Shrug /> This is more the rule than the exception for technical books.  When non-security professionals offer security advice, it is often poor quality.

Comment: How about 0 chars? And only if validated on the server.

Comment: @Xander That statement causes me much distress. I'm certainly no security expert either but my one paragraph probably decimates anything which that book has to offer. I guess [Argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) still has an unfathomable popularity. The only minisculey possible saving grace for that book would be if parameterization was not supported in that version of SQL Server. Also, if that is the rule more than the exception then we're gonna have a mighty fine fire.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree that it's distressing, but I've made a bit of a hobby of reviewing the security advice in technical books and programming books in particular. The coverage is generally either abysmal, or completely absent.  For instance, I have a book on building e-commerce systems from the ground up that briefly discusses the use of HTTPS, and then declares that further discussions on security were "outside the scope" of the book.

Comment: @Xander I'd say that "look elsewhere" is more noble than brazenly claiming something like "Obfuscate your form data using JavaScript and a random key generated by the server before sending data to your server." At least that e-commerce book is saying "Hey guy, we don't want your server to get ducked with a sandpaper phallus so if you care about security then get a good book about it. Our book just teaches you how build an e-commerce site, not how to secure one."

Comment: I'm against book burning on principle - but would vote to bring back the stocks for the authors - "which usually leads to a T-SQL syntax error" -  the whole point of SQL Injection is to get your submitted data to interact outwith the bounds of the intended destination.

Comment: As per other answers, short field lengths won't prevent issues.  I recently worked on a legacy application with an 8 character username field (and 8 characters was checked in code), but it was still open to SQL injection. Things were made worse when the password field was also used in the injection.

Comment: While I agree 100% about how poorly these security problems are usually tackled and how bad the advice from that book is, I think that that advice is bad mainly because it's very likely to allow people to fool themselves into thinking that by taking that "precaution" they protected themselves against SQL injection, and it's also bad because it encourages pursuing risk reduction in a case where risk elimination would be possible (and easy). There is no way to deny that that quote doesn't claim to prevent SQL injection; it just claims to "reduce the likelihood" (which is silly and misleading).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Many DB APIs *still* fail to support array-valued parameters, such as those for the right side of operator `IN`. To work around this, you need to include a variable number of parameters in a query, at which point you end up "pasting together" a list of placeholders, and keeping the order of positional placeholders (`?`) in sync between the statement and the value array is as hard as escaping.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

No, there is no length that is too short to be exploitable (at least in some situations).

A length-filter is not a valid protection against SQL injection, and prepared statements really are the only proper defense.

A length filter is however a good measure as defense in depth (as are integer filters, alphanum filters, etc). There are many situations where e.g. valid input could never be above say 30 characters, but where meaningful exploitation requires more. It should (but probably doesn't) go without saying that any filtering as defense in depth must be taking place server-side as anything client-side can simply be bypassed.

**Restriction Bypass**

Restriction clauses (e.g. `AND`/`OR`) can be bypassed by two characters, which can cause real harm, not just a failed query. The most simple example is a login (other examples would be the unauthorized deletion of additional data):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = [id] AND password = [password]
```

Injection:

```
id = 1#
password = wrong_password
```

Payload: 2 chars

**DoS**

DoS attacks require very few characters. In a MySQL example, it takes 7 for the actual call + x for the given seconds + whatever is needed to be able to call the function and fix the query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = [id]
```

Injection (this is a valid injection, a longer form would be `1 AND sleep(99)`):

```
sleep(99)
```

Payload: 9 chars

### Reading Data

If the data is displayed, the length depends mainly on the table and column name. I'll assume equal column count for all tables (it may happen, and it saves characters).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid = [id]
```

Injection:

```
1 union select * from users
```

Payload: 27 chars.

### Editing Data

Unauthorized database modifications can also be achieved with few characters.

Example:

```
UPDATE users SET password = '[password]' WHERE id = [id]
```

Injection (into password):

```
',isadmin='1
```

Payload: 12 chars

A restriction bypass would also work (the result is that all passwords are now empty*):

```
'#
```

Payload: 2 chars

<sub>* The password example is used for simplicity; passwords should be hashed making the example impossible. The example still applies in all similar situations (updating a username, updating permissions, and so on)</sub>

Comment: `A length-filter is not a valid protection against SQL injection, and prepared statements really are the only proper defense.` This is the only valid answer. SQL without Prepared Statements remind me of ["Strategies how to ride a dead horse"](http://www.deadhorses.org/)

Comment: Good luck preparing a statement with a variable number of placeholders, such as the right side of operator `IN`.

Comment: @DamianYerrick I think that's a flawed hypothetical. Why would you need to provide an end user endless combinations of placeholders for an `IN` clause? It's easy enough to have a handful of templates that allow 1..n (for a small n).

Comment: In "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = [id]" you can inject a if a is the name of a column, so then you have an injection of only 1 character.

Comment: @ShawnC The use case is that a user enters a list of items to be queried. For one thing, how large is "a small n"? It'd seem to violate the zero-one-infinity rule. For another, if there are two different list-valued input fields, you now need to store and test O(n^2) templates.

Comment: @Alexander: Please note that you cannot always use prepared statements as they can't parameterize over field names. And when you have to construct your joins from user input, your job just got a lot harder ...

Comment: @Joshua These are special cases, >99% of the non-parameterized queries can be parameterized without much hassle. And for the special cases, enforcing that field names have to adhere to `[a-zA-Z]+` is much easier than to allow certain special characters in values, and disallow others. Fun facts: When I switched to parameterized queries in PHP, the main issue was to find a provider that had mysqli enabled. [My main issue in DotNet was the `IN` clause.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143012/sqlparameter-and-in-statement)

Comment: @Alexander: Is there any security problem with run-time generating a query of the form `SELECT [whatever] from MyTable where id=@@p0 OR id=@@p1 OR id=@@p2` for whatever number of parameters the user enters, if none of the text of the parameters is included in the statement?

Answer (score 89):

Without context, I'm going to presume that the author is referring to input fields in a client application. The easiest example to use would be a form in an HTML page in a web application, though what I'm about to describe is effective for virtually any type of client application.

Given this context, the answer is no, there is no maximum input field length short enough to protect you from SQL injection, because *you don't control the maximum input field length*. The attacker does. When the form containing the input field lives on the client (like in a browser window on the attacker's machine) it is outside of the trust boundary, and out of your control. It can be manipulated in any way the attacker wants or needs, or avoided completely. Remember, for a web app, all you get is an HTTP request. You have no idea how it was created, and no reason to believe that anything you asked the browser to do actually happened, that any client-side security controls were actually run, that *anything* in the request is as you intended or in any way safe.

So no, input field length is not a valid SQL injection prevention mechanism, and never, never trust input that crosses a security boundary without validating it.

Comment: it's a good answer, maybe the author means a too short field reduces the likelihood to get information from databases, but it can't avoid a harm from a SQL Injection, for example, `or 1=1` can cause great damage.

Comment: @hmrojas.p It doesn't though, because an input filed max length doesn't actually prevent a malicious user from sending as much data as he or she wants in that field.  I can set an input maximum length to 3, and an attacker could still send or 1=1;drop table users;--  If you don't check on the server side, there's nothing preventing this.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I was assuming that there was a length validation on server side, I mean that kind of SQL Injection ( `or 1=1` ) could affect a SQL query like UPDATE or DELETE, it could break the data integrity, even if you have a lenght validation on server side, this measure is complementary.

Comment: So then, what about if the server does that validation then. Malicious users cant touch that. If my PHP script uses only up to the first x characters (which is extremely simple to do and could be done in the middle of the query), then what?

Comment: @Ryan That is in fact the key.  *That* would be the security control. Setting the maximum length of the input field is a nice for the UX, but has no security value.  It is the server-side input validation that provides security.  This is a fundamental and important distinction.  It's a theoretical distinction since the correct answer is to use parameterized queries, but looking strictly at input management, it is still an important distinction.

Comment: I downvoted because this assumes that the field length is not validated server side. While I agree that any answer should mention that the length has to be validated server side and outside the control of the user to be of any use, I believe that server side validation of length would cmpletely invalidate your entire answer. (The answer might still be no, but not for this reason.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Whether it is validated server-side is irrelevant.  The context of the quote is a client-side "security" measure, and server side validation is not addressed.

Comment: @Xander The only person who has assumed client-side-only validation here is you. I see nothing in the question or comments that suggests this is the situation the OP is describing.

Comment: @jpmc26 From the question: *"input fields as small as possible"*. Does the server know what an input field is when it receives a response? I mean if you submit an HTML form, the server doesn't have a concept of "input field". It just gets the data. I think without context from the book, the quote is kinda ambiguous.

Comment: @JacobAlvarez The server obviously knows what the inputs are and can discern the values if it can stuff them into a SQL query where injection can occur. If it can discern the values, it can determine the length. Don't get me wrong; the quote is nonsense. But so is making up unrelated reasons about why it's nonsense, so let's get the reasons right.

Comment: @jpmc26, the citation says "input field". That is where user interaction happens. So it's clear to me that it's about the client side, not the server side. The same goes for forms that do JS input validation. Unless it is *explicitly stated* that the validation is *repeated* server-side, it's safe to assume that server-side validation is non-existent.

Comment: @aross For all we know, we could be talking about a REST interface that doesn't even provide a GUI. "Input field" means nothing more to me than the value is user generated. Mentioning that the length validation must be done in an environment the user doesn't control is definitely appropriate. Assuming that it doesn't happen and making that the basis of an *entire* answer is actually just avoiding answering the question at all.

Comment: @jpmc26 You seem to be conflating parameters with input fields.

Comment: @aross I seem to be thinking about the fact that the values from these "input fields" end up *in a SQL query*. There is no practical difference, and "input field" is not that strictly defined. The notion that this is client side only validation is a *completely unwarranted assumption* worthy of no more than a side note. It answers *nothing* about the question of whether length matters in the context of SQL injection.

Comment: Well, if we're starting a discussion about semantics, here's some sources: [input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_(computer_science)), [parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54700/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-aross).

Answer (score 11):

> input fields as small as possible to reduce the likelihood of a hacker being able to squeeze SQL code into the field without it being truncated (which usually leads to a T-SQL syntax error).

IMHO, this is just shit. Using the length of input fields to protect from SQL injection is terrible advice:

- The only correct way to protect from SQL injection is the use of a prepared statement. The input data is a **parameter** of the query and will never be used as SQL text.
- The size of a field must be controlled *server side* because you can never trust what comes in a request - it might be a forged one - and should be used to sanitize data before usage in the business layer or database storage.
- Advice to use anything other than the best practices is confusing for novice developers.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

Consider the query:

```
select * from tweets
WHERE RowNum >= [offset]
AND RowNum < [offset] + [limit]
```

If you could inject a single non-integer (for example, the letter "a") for `offset`, the query would result in a syntax error and no posts would show up yielding your "results not intended by design" requirement for causing damage. If you can inject an empty string you get the same effect with a zero length payload. Injecting an end comment would be a waste of two characters ;)

An attacker can leverage this in a denial of service attack (differently from a [network flooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Application-layer_floods) generally associated with DoS, yet still a [DoS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Denial_of_Service)). Depending on the service being denied, this could be catastrophic.

As other answers suggest field length has no bearing on the SQL injection impact. Prepared, parameterized statements are the way to go as mentioned in the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Denial of service and SQL injection are two very different things.  This answer does not offer anything helpful that is not already addressed in existing answers.

Comment: Correct, SQL injection is one form of the "injection attack" category, that can yield many different ends including denial of service. Denial of service is a technique can be achieved through different vectors. A common one is via a distributed flood. But any technique that yields an unresponsive service is properly classified a denial of service attack. This can include SQL injection. My answer provides an explanation of how this can be done with zero characters. It also provides a link to the OWASP SQL injection Prevention Cheat Sheet. Thanks for pointing out that I should highlight those.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Simple example of a one-character SQL injection:

```
`
```

It would throw an error which would be an example of "returning results not intended by design". Many times errors can be used to gain information that will help later in an exploit.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an explanation on how that injection could be harmful?

Comment: It would an error which would be an example of `returning results not intended by design` Many times errors can be used to gain information that will help later in an exploit.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty of including your explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The maximum length is zero. The only way to make untrusted input safe via maximum length, with no other validation or checks, is to completely disregard the input starting at index 0.

There are many other (better) answers here, but this one serves to answer the theoretical question of how to stay safe when field length is the only tool at your disposal.

Comment: I'm honestly not convinced that a clever enough attacker couldn't manage an attack with zero characters.

Comment: Along the lines of other comments above -- where any results not intended by design is some form of  SQL injection; would it also be valid to say that any behavior not intended by design is a form of Sql injection (referring to the sleep(60) example above .. which was kind of cool :)?

A 0 length SQL injection then, would not necessarily have to involve any SQL.... as long as you could tie up the connection??

Comment: @Dan well jeez if I knew that I'd go ahead and make a countermeasure. This is the problem with security in general... We think it's secure until some attacker proves it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a field won't have anything to do with SQL injection, because such an attack works by simply commenting out previous code and starting the attack code, so the length of any field won't effect this strategy.

Comment: I think OP's point is that the application is not going to allow an arbitrary amount of text to reach the database-- it still truncates at a particular length.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of theory here but no actual examples.  When I found a real-world sql injection vulnerability (now patched) I tried using input fields that were around 30 characters long.  This was very frustrating as it took me a while to figure out that everything after 30 characters was dropped, and 30 characters did not leave me room for much.

(a lot of sql injection examples have simple sql "like select * from table where id = @id", real world sql will usually be much more complicated)

You can get fancy with your input, and a sql expert could probably use some tricks to reduce the payload count.  But no matter how tricky you are if you want to select some long table name you're going to need a lot of characters for that.

Anyways, when I switched to using a input field with over 1k characters I found that plenty for sql injection.

That being said, like many commenters above me said, **The best defense against sql injection is prepared statements**